# USB Debugging is not showing in ADB devices

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb-debugging, lg-optimus-l7-2

I Enabled USB Debugging on CyanogenMod 11 for LG Optimus L7. The Device is showing in Device Manager.

But, it is not showing in ADB devices list. And there is no notifications for USB debugging.

Comment: What is the device listed as in device manager?

Comment: Reflashed the ROM.Found in adb devices But No Notifications

Answer (score 2):

I find solution for this problem..

steps:

1. Download Google USB Driver.
   [please find your device USB Driver from this link.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)
2. Then open devices in windows.
3. After that right-click on devices open property.
4. select update device driver.
5. Then select pickup from disk & select path of download Google USB driver.
6. Then type into command prompt at android-sdk\platform-tools
7. adb kill-server
8. adb start-server
9. adb devices

   after all this you get your android devices.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're comfortable with using Android Debug Bridge (ADB), you can try the following steps in order:

1)  Open a command prompt (Windows) or shell prompt (Linux) at `android-sdk\platform-tools` directory.

2) Type `adb kill-server`

3) Type `adb start-server`

4) Type `adb devices`

If your device does not show up, try updating the Android SDK to the latest version and repeat the above steps again.

Comment: Tried Not Showing Up ....

Comment: @ArulNadhan: Hate to point out the obvious, but have you installed the LG USB drivers for your device onto your operating system (Windows, Linux)? Without these drivers, ADB initially won't work.

Comment: Reflashed the ROM.Found in adb devices. But No Notification is not showing up...

Answer (score 0):

This has always been a problem. Try this, always works for me.

1. Ensure debugging is enabled
2. Install device drivers
3. If it still doesn't work use this
   http://koush.com/post/universal-adb-driver, reboot and try again
   should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking the settings of your device. Just like the usb debugging in Developer settings in stock android. Scroll down to # Superuser on the settings panel and tap. At least on my Sorry Xpendaple Goo running Cyanogenmod 11 rc 1, on the upper right corner there's the icon for the log and three dashes or dots. Tap them dots and select settings. Under Security, tap Superuser permissions and select Apps and ADB. Or Only ADB.